# WebBrowser control session sharing?

Tags: session, cookies, webbrowser-control

I host the IE's WebBrowser control (CLSID_WebBrowser) in a desktop windows application. This WB seems to store its session cookies independently of the machine's Internet Explorer (IE9, Win7).

I want to rely on this behavior but can't find any proof of it. Has anyone seen any documentation regarding the session sharing? Has it been so in the previous IE versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it seems that we can't make such assumption and can't rely on it in the production code.

I've tried different setups and here are the results:

1. WinXP, IE6: Session is shared
2. WinXP, IE7: Session is shared
3. WinXP, IE8: Session is shared (with both LCIE enabled and disabled)
4. Win7, IE9, LCIE disabled: Session is shared
5. Win7, IE9, LCIE enabled: Session is NOT shared.

The closest info I could find about it is in the reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403342/419450), but it's seems to be incorrect.

Comment: From what I understand, it has to do with IE8 and IE9 in protected-mode running as a low-priority process in Vista/7.

Comment: What is LCIE and how to make sure it is disabled? Is it enabled or disabled by default? How about Win8/IE10?

Comment: @wpfwannabe: LCIE is a loosely-coupled IE, check out [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx) for more information. It's enabled by default and I believe it'll stay enabled for every new IE since 8.0.

Comment: So I am assuming there is no way to share the session without user first manually disabling this, right?

Comment: Not that I know of. We actually needed the other way around - to not share the session.